# Aggregate Function in Excel with CountIF Function

Tags: excel, aggregate, countif

Is there any way to use excel aggregate function on a countif formula? I am counting text words within a cell which can have multiple counts but I want to be to be able to filter it with the aggregate function

Comment: Your question is not that clear, but if there are some functions such as `sumif` I am not sure you can just use whatever aggregate function, if excel has it, you can use it otherwise you have to use VBA to define it

Comment: Yes, there is.  What, exactly, are you trying to do? Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question so as to clarify your exact problem.